# Can anyone identify this pedal a Jamis Nova road bike?

Tags: road-bike, pedals, pedals-clipless

Can anyone identify this pedal on a Jamis Nova road bike?

This is my first road bike and I'm prepping to take it out for a spin. I know this is a MTB pedal, I'm just wondering if is Shimano SPD? Whether or not it is, can you recommend cleat brands/types that will fit?

[image]

[image]

[image]

<sup>Pictures are from https://www.tumblr.com/blog/view/cptrorshak/690256235115823105</sup>

Comment: Tumblr is asking me to login to see full-sized versions of the photos. I'm not gonna do that. Can you post them directly to question?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure who the original manufacturer is, but it appears to be a Shimano SPD compatible "campus" pedal. A campus pedal is one with a cleat attachment on one side, and a typical platform surface on the other for use with normal shoes.

Shimano SH-51 or SH-56 or any number of the aftermarket SPD compatible cleats should work.

The majority of mountain biking shoes accept two-screw cleats by default, but that would be the thing to look for in shoes.

Comment: We generally don't make specific shoe, clothing or part recommendations beyond this kind of general advice because product recommendations go out of date very quickly